# Stack Windows Manager Program How-to's

Tags: stack, window-management

I download the Stack Windows Manager from Microsoft store.  Someone introduced it to me and said it is a great program.
Oddly, after installing it and setting it up, I cannot find out how to start using it? There is no instruction to show me how to at least organize my desktop into this "layout tool".   Is there a video anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Stackoverflow is a site for developers and code.  You might try posting your comment on https://superuser.com/, which is intended for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

At the first launch on each screen it shows you a few layouts to select from.

After you made the selection, either use Win+Arrow keys to move windows around, or drag windows between areas with middle mouse button (usually it is also the scroll button).